# Why is drawString not updating values?

Tags: java, draw, paintcomponent

I am drawing this (in the paint method):

```
g.drawString("NumPipes: " + numPipes + "   " + "DeletedPipes: " + deletedPipes + "    moved: " + numMoved, 0 , 10);
```

To output the values defined in these following methods:

```
public void addPipe() {
    for (int i = 0; i < pipe.length; i++) {
        if (pipe[i] == null) {
            pipe[i] = new Pipe(this.width, (int) Math.random() * (this.height - 200));
            System.out.println("Pipe Added.");
            numPipes += 1;
        }
    }
}

public void deletePipe() {
    for (int i = 0; i < pipe.length; i++) {
        if (pipe[i] != null && pipe[i].returnX() <= 0) {
            pipe[i] = null;
            System.out.println("Pipe Deleted.");
            deletedPipes += 1;
        }
    }
}

public void movePipe(int speed) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pipe.length; i++) {
        if (pipe[i] != null) {
            pipe[i].move(speed);
            numMoved = numMoved + 1;
            System.out.println(numMoved);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I check the console for the outputted value of `numMoved`, the values are increasing/updating but they stay the same in the `JFrame` (See below image, the console displays the value of `numMoved` and the `JFrame` shows the `drawString` values). What is happening/Why is it doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be calling `repaint`, so that component doesn't know that it should update the values...

For example...

```
public void addPipe() {
    for (int i = 0; i < pipe.length; i++) {
        if (pipe[i] == null) {
            pipe[i] = new Pipe(this.width, (int) Math.random() * (this.height - 200));
            System.out.println("Pipe Added.");
            numPipes += 1;
        }
    }
    repaint();
}
```

Now, you could place `repaint` after `numPipes += 1`, but because of the way `repaint` works, it probably won't make a difference...

This assumes that the class that `addPipe` belongs to is some kind of component, but you've not supplied enough information to make proper diagnoses...

Comment: omg... Yea thanks. I will probably close this question now due to the syntax/simple error.. Thanks though.

Comment: I do this all the time :P